# Cython: disable automatic type conversion

Tags: cython

I have one cpp file like this:

```
namespace MyNamespace {
        struct MyStruct {                                                                                                                                        
        std::unordered_set<index> field1;                                                                                                                            
        std::unordered_set<index> field2; 
}
```

I haven't done any wrapping for `MyStruct`.

Then in Cython file, I try to access `field1` of a `MyStruct` object (returned by some function, details omitted).

However, Cython [automatically converts](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html#automatic-type-conversions) the `struct` to `dict`, which actually evaluates to `{}` (But I'm not sure why).

So is there a way to disable the conversion temporally?

Comment: Please add (some of) the omitted details, so we know what you are trying to achieve. See also [mcve].

Comment: Your function is probably returning a Python-object and not MyStruct, but without seeing code it is impossible to tell.